# Calculating Euler Number limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Please, so far I did
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x-1}},$$ but I can write
$$\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+2}=1+\frac{x^2-2x-1}{x+2}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{x^2-2x-1}}.$$
But
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x+2}{x^2-2x-1}=0,$$ so I can not use 
$$e =\lim_{N\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{N})^N$$

Comment: You can not take limits "half baked". Either you take the limit on the whole expression or you don't. Taking a limit on that fraction  and then continue to calculate with the "result" is not correct

Comment: It looks like we should use the less known $1=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$

Answer (score 2):

Take the natural log of this mess and you'll get:

$$\ln(L)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2-x+1)-\ln(x+2)}{x-1}$$

By applying L'Hospital's rule, we end up with

$$\ln(L)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+4x-3}{(x+2)(x^2-x+1)}=0$$

Thus,

$$L=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for sufficiently large $x$,

\begin{align}
1 < \left(\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+2}\right)^\frac{1}{x-1}
    & = \left(x-3+\frac{7}{x+2}\right)^\frac{1}{x-1} \\
    & < (x-1)^\frac{1}{x-1}
\end{align}

which has a well-known limit as $x \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle y=\left(\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ then 
$$\ln y= \frac{1}{x-1}\ln(x^2-x+1)-\frac{1}{x-1}\ln(x+2)$$
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}-\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x+2}=0,\ L'Hopital$$
Then $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}y=1$